# A/The laptop which I bought in the UK is faulty

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article, relative-clauses

Are the statements below wrong? Thanks!

> 1. The laptop which I bought in the UK is faulty.

analysis: You know I bought only one laptop visiting the UK and it's faulty.

> 2. A laptop which I bought in the UK is faulty.

analysis: You know I bought more that one laptop in the UK and one of these laptops is faulty.

> 3. A laptop that I bought in the UK is faulty.

analysis: The indefinite article “A”  means of all the laptops in the world one is faulty. You bought it in the UK. You don't know whether I bought one or more.

> 4. The laptop that I bought in the UK is faulty.

analysis: Of all the laptops in the world faulty is the one you bought in the UK. You don't know whether I bought one or more.

Comment: Except for #2, all look fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analysis is mostly incorrect, especially the ideas around being able to discern how many laptops there are or which ones are faulty.

Here would be the correct analyses:

> 1. The laptop**,** which I bought in the UK**,** is faulty.

Firstly, I was always taught to use commas when using "which", as it comes across as much more of an "aside" type of comment than "that". "Which" also sounds a lot more formal to me, and I think you'd be much more likely to see it written than hear it spoken.

Using "the", to describe the laptop, alerts the listener that you are talking about a specific laptop, and that they should be aware of which laptop this is (perhaps you mentioned it already).

> 2. A laptop, which I bought in the UK, is faulty.

Here, you are talking about some random/generic laptop ("**a** laptop") purchased in the UK. This is not a particularly idiomatic phrasing.

> 3. A laptop that I bought in the UK is faulty.

As mentioned previously, "that" is much more direct than "which" and so doesn't need the commas. Also, you could easily remove "that" from this sentence and it would mean the same thing. This is a very simple statement, where you're just stating that some laptop you bought in the UK is faulty.

> 4. The laptop that I bought in the UK is faulty.

This is the one where you are suggesting that you purchased multiple laptops, that only one was purchased in the UK, and that the one from the UK is faulty.

You could use "which" (as in 1) to remove this suggestion (as it makes the fact that you purchased it in the UK an "aside" comment), or you could also punctuate to achieve the same effect/meaning:

> The laptop that I bought, in the UK, is faulty.

One other thing to consider, is that you could also use the past tense "was faulty" in these sentences. In that way, you'd be referring to having discovered in the past that the laptop **was** faulty.

**'The', 'A', 'One of'**

Base on the discussion in the comments, I offer the following clarification/explanation:

"The" lets us know that it is one, and the only one.

"A"/"An" lets us know that it is one (there may be others, or not).

"One of" lets us know that it is one of some group or collection.

Now, consider that it would have been perfectly acceptable for me to say above:

> Base on the discussion in the comments, I offer a clarification:

Yet how many clarifications are there? Only one.

Comment: So none of the statements tell you how many laptops I bought in the UK?

If I say **That's the laptop [which] I bought in the UK** do you now know that I bought only one laptop in the UK? And If I say **That's a laptop [which] I bought in the UK** are you now aware of the fact that I bought more that one laptop there?

Comment: Only statement 4 suggests that you bought more than 1 laptop (as detailed in my answer). "That's the laptop I bought in the UK" does also suggest you only bought one laptop in the UK (there's no need for "which" in that sentence). "That's a laptop I bought in the UK" only informs the listener that the laptop in question was purchased in the UK, but doesn't highlight it as "*the* one" laptop you purchased in the UK.

Comment: **That's a program which I use to trim video** You know I use some other programs to trim video, right?

Comment: No, all you've said is that the program in question is something you use to trim video. To specify that you use other programs, say "That's one of the programs I use to trim video."

Comment: There's an explanation I got from a native English speaker. It's controversial with your last answer. **...if they say "That's a program which I use", we know that this is only one of several programs which they use. The use of the indefinite article (singular) and the zero article (plural) indicates the existence of other things in this category.**

Comment: That explanation is incorrect. Consider the difference between the following phrases from your comment: 1) That's a program. 2) That's one of several programs. Also, what are you describing as "zero article (plural)"?

Comment: How could it be? I got the explanation on italki and it was a woman from the UK. The more I try to figure this stuff out the harder it gets.

Comment: Do you have a link to the explanation? Perhaps you could ask a new question seeking clarity on it.

Comment: https://www.italki.com/question/483648

Comment: That answer is incorrect - I've updated my answer, which will hopefully clarify things for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102984/discussion-between-through-the-wonders-and-chris-mack).